# declare function with overrides with one required and multiple inferred generics

Tags: typescript, generics, inferred-type

Trying to do something like this:

```
declare function pipe<S, T1>(op1: OperatorFn<S, T1>): T1
declare function pipe<S, T1, T2>(op1: OperatorFn<S, T1>, op2: OperatorFn<T1, T2>): T2
declare function pipe<S, T1, T2, T3>(op1: OperatorFn<S, T1>, op2: OperatorFn<T1, T2>, op3: OperatorFn<T2,T3>): T3
```

I want S to be required, but I want to the rest to be inferred - whatever op1 returns is T1, whatever op2 returns is T2, if you know what I mean.

I know what I have above doesn't work, not at all sure how to make it work in my definition file, though.

EDIT:
I know I can write something like this:

```
export interface pipe<S> {
    <T1>(op1: OperatorFn<S, T1>): S;
    <T1,T2>(op1: OperatorFn<S, T1>, op2: OperatorFn<T1,T2>): S;
}
```

But I need to declare a function in my interface file that then adheres to that interface. Not sure how to do that either.

EDIT #2:

The below seems to solve my problem easily enough:

```
type pipe<S> = <T1,T2>(op1: OperatorFn<S,T1>, op2?: OperatorFn<T1,T2>) => S
```

But then I don't know how to declare a function that adheres to that type in my definition file.

Comment: IIRC TypeScript doesn't support supplying only one generic type, e.g. `pipe<string>(...)`, if you supply any you have to supply all.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I'm aware what I have written won't work, but I was wondering if I could write it in a different way, like what's in my edit. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: Could the person who close voted suggest what details or clarify might benefit this question? I'll be happy to add them.

Comment: *"I don't know how to declare a function that adheres to that type"* - `const impl: pipe<string> = (op) => "hi";`, for example. But I think the actual return type should be `T2` if `op2` is provided, `T1` otherwise. Maybe have a look at e.g. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Observable.ts#L337-L429.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I can write it in typescript, but I'm having trouble writing the declarations in a definition file.

Comment: Just `declare const impl: pipe<string>` then, or get TSC to generate the declarations for you. It's still not totally clear to me what specific problem you're trying to solve, can you step back and [edit] to give some context?

Answer (score 0):

Because `T1` is not used anywhere else than inside the function, it allows you to do this.

This can easily extended with `type T2 = typeof op2` and so on.

```js
function pipe<S>(op1: OperatorFn<unkown, unknown>): S {
   type T1 = typeof op1 extends TEST<S, infer U> ? U : never
}
```

---

You also have to extend type `S` to match `OperatorFn`.